# Why Request object from Controller doesn't contain data information when i used Ajax to update entity?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, formbuilder

I try to updtae post entity with Ajax from Form...

**PostControler.php:**

```
<?php

namespace BISSAP\ForumBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Post;
use BISSAP\ForumBundle\Form\PostType;


class PostController extends Controller
{


    public function editAction($id)
    {
           ...
    }

    public function updateAction(Request $request)
    {
        $id = 14;
        if ($this->container->get('request')->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('BISSAPForumBundle:Post')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Post entity.');
        }

        $editPostForm = $this->createForm(new PostType(true), $entity);
        $editPostForm->handleRequest($request);

                if ($editPostForm->isValid()) {
                $em->flush();
                return $this
                    ->container
                    ->get('templating')
                    ->renderResponse('BISSAPForumBundle:Post:update.html.twig', array('post' => $entity));        
                }

                $errorform = var_dump($editPostForm->getErrors(true));;
                return $this->render('BISSAPForumBundle:Post:test.html.twig', array('output' => $output));
        }


    }

}
```

When I explore `$request` where `var_dump`, there isn't any form informations (like content or name form...),Maybe, is for this reason that `isValid()` return false.

**Part of PostType:**

```
$entity = $builder->getData();

            $builder
                    ->add('content', 'ckeditor', array(
                        'label' => 'Votre message',
                        'config_name' => 'edit_post',
                        'config' => array('language' => 'fr')))
                    ->add('Envoyer', 'submit', array(
                        'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'btn right-flt',
                        'data-id' => $entity->getId())))
            ;
```

**AJAX on click :**

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', ".comment .content form button", function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var route = $this.closest("form").attr("action");
    var type = $this.closest("form").attr("method");
    var id = $this.data('id');
    console.log(route);
    console.log(type);  
        $.ajax({type: type, dataType: 'html', url: route, success: function(response){
            console.log(response);


            $('#message-'+id).html(response);

        }, error: function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR.status);
            console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }});
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: how do you know that there is no data?

Comment: I think @NandaKumar is right. You aren't passing any data to your ajax call

Comment: @Frankbeen =>  explore $request where var_dump, and i compar when i no use AJAX.

Comment: No need for: $this->container->get('request'), the request object is already being passed to updateAction.  Won't fix the ajax issue but will clean up some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding data to ajax call could solve this problem

```
$.ajax({
    type:"type",
    url: "url",
    data: $("form").serialize()
});
```

Comment: Thank NandaKumar, but why i need to use this, and why my resquest Object is not full when i use AJAX?! if i use "POST in $.ajax() I should be able to get post data in request object... no?

Comment: So, i tried with serialize(), now isvalid return true, and i have some form information in object Request, but serialize not take into account the modification for content. thx

Comment: In ajax you are doing the asynchronous call to perform the actions but not the data whereas normal form submit you are hitting the corresponding form action url along with the data. 
You need to explicitly pass the data for the ajax calls.

Comment: I replace `$(document).on('click', ".comment .content form button", function(e) {})` by  `$(document).on('submit', "form", function(e) {})` and now i get data modified field from the form in object Request

Answer (score 3):

Clarifying moments:

1. Why you use dataType: 'html' in your ajax request?
2. I dont see 'data' property of object you passed to $.ajax
3. I dont worked with PHP and JS long time, but I remember that I was serialize form using jQuery method and then pass it to ajax object into data section, dataType I was set to json.

Hope this will help to you somehow :)

Comment: 1) Hi excluded_once, i use dataType:'html' cause i need to get html result to inject in my div. I'm going to learn this. 2) indeed other uses data: $("form").serialize somthing like this..but I want to understand why Resquest Object is different when i use AJAX...